# Angular Error Handler

Tags: angular, angular-errorhandler

I have implemented a global error handler in my app. My problem with it at the moment is that it is intercepting the client related errors but it is **not** intercepting any server error for http calls. This is how the error handler implementation looks like:

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NotificationService } from '@app/services/notification.service';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private _injector: Injector) { }

    handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse) {        
        const notificationService: this._injector.get(NotificationService);
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            // Server error happened (this DOES NOT get intercepted)
            if (!navigator.onLine) {
                // No Internet connection
                return notificationService.notify('No Internet Connection');
            }
            // Http Error (this DOES NOT get intercepted)
            return notificationService.notify(`${error.status} - ${error.message}`);
        } else {
            // Client Error Happend (this gets intercepted)
            console.error(error);
        }
        // Log the error anyway
        console.error(error);
    }    
}
```

I am providing the **`GlobalErrorHandler`** in **`AppModule`** like this:

```
providers: [ 
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler}
]
```

Any ideas why the **http** error are not being intercepted by the handler?

Comment: Should it not be `if (error.error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {...` since you are looking for the [`error` property of `HttpErrorResponse`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse#properties)

Comment: @Und3rTow no, **`error instanceof HttpErrorResponse`** is correct.